# XAMPP not parsing PHP

Tags: php, parsing, xampp

I just installed XAMPP 1.8.1 and have restarted my computer, started running Apache and MySQL, and created a test file in a test folder in my htdocs directory under XAMPP.

When I go to xampp/index.php, their page comes up fine. But my test file only returns the actual characters in my PHP file in the "Response" tab in firebug, but a completely blank white screen in the window. The file is definitely .php extension - can anyone help?

The crazy thing is, I had this working 6 months ago just fine and have just gotten back to it on a new install.

Comment: is the `phpmyadmin` and `index.php` of xampp working fine?

Comment: Yes it is, that's the weird thing..

Comment: Can you post your test.php code. full page code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you might be using short tag `<? ?>` or `<?= ?>` instead of `<?php ?>`.
Check your **php.ini**. It locates at **\path\to\xampp\php\php.ini**. The `short_open_tag` should be **On**.

> ; Allow the `<?` tag.  Otherwise, only `<?php` and `<script>` tags are recognized.
>   ; NOTE: Using short tags should be avoided when developing applications or
>   ; libraries that are meant for redistribution, or deployment on PHP
>   ; servers which are not under your control, because short tags may not
>   ; be supported on the target server. For portable,redistributable code, be sure not to use short tags.
>   short_open_tag = On

Comment: No Way!!! That is rediculous, wasting an hour on that. Thankyou so much, in 7 mins I will accept your answer :-P Many thanks

Comment: As a side note, if you update php.ini, you will have to restart apache.