# I am unable to link my html forms to mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a forms page named "employee.php" for taking in user data. Also I have another file named SQLConnectionProcess.php which contains the code for linking forms in employee.php to sql table. The name of the database is "employee information" and the table's name is "employee info". I am using phpmyadmin and XAMPP for local server testing.

employee.php code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="EmployeeDatabase" action="SQLConnectionProcess.php" method="post">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

<h1>EMPLOYEE DATABASE</h1>

Employe Card NO: <input type="text" name="cardNO" ><br><br>
Employee NO: <input type="text" name="employeeNO" ><br><br>
Employee Name: <input type="text" name="employeename"><br><br>
Nationality: <input type="text" name="nationality"><br><br>
Profession: <input type="text" name="profession"><br><br>
DOB: <input type="text" name="DOB"><br><br>
DOJ: <input type="text" name="DOJ"><br><br>
DOA(VisitVisa): <input type="text" name="DOA"><br><br>
Company Code: <input type="text" name="companycode"><br><br>
Sponsor Code: <input type="text" name="sponsorcode"><br><br>
Visa Type: <input type="text" name="visatype"><br><br>
Status: <input type="text" name="status"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

SQLConnectionProcess.php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
  $cardNO= $_POST['cardNO'];
  $employeeNO= $_POST['employeeNO'];
  $employeename= $_POST['employeename'];
  $nationality= $_POST['nationality'];
  $profession= $_POST['profession'];
  $DOB= $_POST['DOB'];
  $DOJ= $_POST['DOJ'];
  $DOA= $_POST['DOA'];
  $companycode = $_POST['companycode'];
  $sponsorcode= $_POST['sponsorcode'];
  $visatype= $_POST['visatype'];
  $status= $_POST['status'];
  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','employee information');
  $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table_employee info(Employee Card NO,Employee NO,Employee Name,Nationality,Profession,DOB,DOJ,DOA(VisitVisa),Company Code,Sponsor Code,Visa Type,Status) VALUES ('','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",$cardNO,$employeeNO,$employeename,$nationality,$profession,$DOB,$DOJ,$DOA,$companycode,$sponsorcode,$visatype,$status);
  mysqli_query($sql);
```

But when I submit my forms from employee.php I get redirected to a new page which displays all the code in SQLConnectionProcess.php. I am unable to figure out the coding error. Kindly help me.....

Comment: add line  ini_set("display_errors",1); in front of your code. and see the error.

Comment: Take a look at your apache configuration file... it sounds like you php module is not loaded

Comment: Use <?php ?> tag also "}" closing of if is missing.

Comment: I added <?php and ?> to open and close the codes in SQLConnectionProcess.php . Is that necessary ? If yes then when I run it now the error I get is: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 20"

Comment: yes because } bracket missing. @Gotham

Comment: I added "}" thanks. The new errors I am now getting are: "
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 18"

Comment: where is your database connection?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. I am inexperienced in this  subject. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code.

**SQLConnectionProcess.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
  $cardNO= isset($_POST['cardNO']) ? $_POST['cardNO'] : 0;
  $employeeNO= isset($_POST['employeeNO']) ? $_POST['employeeNO'] : 0;
  $employeename= isset($_POST['employeename']) ? $_POST['employeename'] : "";
  $nationality= isset($_POST['nationality']) ? $_POST['nationality'] : "";
  $profession= isset($_POST['profession']) ? $_POST['profession'] : "";
  $DOB= isset($_POST['DOB']) ? $_POST['DOB'] : "";
  $DOJ= isset($_POST['DOJ']) ? $_POST['DOJ'] : "";
  $DOA= isset($_POST['DOA']) ? $_POST['DOA'] : "";
  $companycode = isset($_POST['companycode']) ? $_POST['companycode'] : 0;
  $sponsorcode= isset($_POST['sponsorcode']) ? $_POST['sponsorcode'] : 0;
  $visatype= isset($_POST['visatype']) ? $_POST['visatype'] : "";
  $status= isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : "";
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','employee information');
  $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table_employee info(Employee Card NO,Employee NO,Employee Name,Nationality,Profession,DOB,DOJ,DOA(VisitVisa),Company Code,Sponsor Code,Visa Type,Status) VALUES ('','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",$cardNO,$employeeNO,$employeename,$nationality,$profession,$DOB,$DOJ,$DOA,$companycode,$sponsorcode,$visatype,$status);
  mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks again. I tried it. It removed the acces denied error. One error still remaining :Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 18

Comment: Yes I used it. same error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 17

Comment: have you change mysqli_query($sql); with mysqli_query($con,$sql); Please check this line. @Gotham

Comment: Did it. Now two errors : 
Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 17.

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 17

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But unfortunately I am still having errors proping: 
Notice: Undefined variable: emplo‌​yeeNO in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined variable: sponsor‌​code in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 16

Comment: use edited code. I have changed and use isset to prevent from your above error. @Gotham

Answer (score 0):

You server is not parsing PHP-files, instead its serving the file "raw". This is what you need to fix. If you look for this problem you have suggestions for solutions here:

[XAMPP not parsing PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555669/xampp-not-parsing-php)

By the way - this might be obvious, but do you have opening and closing `<?php` tags? Or is the text you posted you entire file

EDIT: And you need to pass the connection like so:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','employee information');
$sql = "...";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

Comment: I added <?php and ?> to open and close the codes in SQLConnectionProcess.php . Also I added "}" to close the if statement. Now I am getting 2 new errors: 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\SQLConnectionProcess.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>';
}
?>
```

check post if working fine after submit